# Use Pandas .set_table_styles() with tr:nth-child Selector and Properties and Render HTML

Tags: python, html, pandas, outlook, pandas-styles

Im new to using pandas styling so im finding this all very difficult but i am trying to take a Pandas Dataframe. Then i want to apply table styling to color `tr:nth-child(odd)` rows a certain color.

I see the code for `set_table_styles()` takes a dictionary of CSS Selectors and Poperties to define these styles.

Im assuming the selector i would want for my table is `'selector':'tr:nth-child(old)'` and props would be `'props'`: `['background': 'blue']`

This how ever produces no striping result and cannot figure this out. I have had suceess with some other style options working but not this one particularly.

In the end i need the rendered HTML because im inserting it into a Email generated bu Microsoft Outlook.

ANy help tot achieve this would be greatly appreciated. Below is a snippet of the text that produces my email but with now table row stripping

````
myMessage = """<HTML>
                    segmentStuffHere
               <HTML>"""

segmentParts = ""

for seg, dF in segmentDataFrames.items():
    html = (
    dF.style
    .set_table_styles([{'selector': 'tr:nth-child(odd)', 'props': [('background', '#FFF')]}])
    .render()
            )
    myMessagePart = """

                    <BODY>
                        <font color="black">
                            The break-out by "{segment}" is as follows:<br><br>
                            {htmlTable}
                            <br>
                        </font>
                    </BODY>


                """.format(htmlTable=html, segment=seg)

    segmentParts += myMessagePart

myMessage = myMessage.replace('segmentStuffHere', segmentParts)
print(myMessage)

# print(myMessage)
outlook = Dispatch("Outlook.Application")

#Contruct a message Body found above ^
# Found the below syntax is needed to build outlook object to send message. 
msg = outlook.CreateItem(0)
msg.To = '{}@email.com'.format('user')
# msg.CC = emailCC

msg.Subject = 'Segment Test'

msg.GetInspector
index = msg.HTMLbody.find('>', msg.HTMLbody.find('<body'))
msg.HTMLbody = msg.HTMLbody[:index + 1] + myMessage + msg.HTMLbody[index + 1:]
# msg.HTMLBody = myMessage

msg.Display(False)
# msg.BodyFormat = '3'
msg.Send()
print('Email Sent!')```
````

Answer (score 0):

upon moving forward in my code and trouble shooting a new problem. . . i stumbled upon a solution that worked perfectly. I was able to write a function and use the .apply() function to do this by row.

```
def style_email_tables(s):
    return ['text-align: center; border-style: solid; border-collapse: collapse; border-width: 1.5px; border-color: #CCD4DC' if s.name % 2 else 'background-color: #EFF2F8; text-align: center; border-style: solid; border-collapse: collapse; border-width: 1.5px; border-color: #CCD4DC' for v in s]

def styleDataFrame(dataFrame, columnSubset=None):
    if columnSubset:
        tableHTML = (
                dataFrame.style.apply(style_email_tables, axis=1)
                        .set_properties(subset=columnSubset, **{'width':'10em', 'text-align':'center'})
                        .set_table_styles([{'selector':'th', 'props': [('border-style','solid'),('border-collapse', 'collapse'),('border-width','1.5px'), ('border-color', '#CCD4DC'), ('text-align', 'center'), ('background', '#102038')]}])
                        .hide_index()
                        .render()
            )
```